# Error with the form action in html WordPress doesn't redirect to the page at all for uploading file

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have this form here that should redirect to another file in the theme that responsible for uploading, the form not even redirect the page on submit but when I write the full path in the URL it goes normally to the file which exist here wp-content/themes/brightlines/assets/uploads.php later on I'm going to pass the dir to Matecat API normally which I tested and works properly. Where is the issue could be involved

```
<div id="PDF" class="tabcontent">       `

<p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>       
     <form action="/wp-content/themes/brightlines/assets/uploads.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">          
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">      
     <br /><input type="submit" name="pdfsubmit" />                
     </form>             
    </div>
```

The uploads.php file code is to check the file if it's uploaded

```
<?php
echo "We are at uploads ";
require('assets/index.php');

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["pdfsubmit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if ($check !== false) {
echo "File is an PDF - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
$uploadOk = 1;
} else {
echo "File is not an image.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if (
$imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx"
) {
echo "Sorry, only PDF, DOC, DOCX";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($\_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

        $Metacat_class = new  Metacat();
        $Metacat_class->MetacatAPI_Connection();
    
        echo "The file " . htmlspecialchars(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])) . " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }

}
```